# Proving the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

*Theorem*

> *The Mean Value Theorem*: Let there be a function $f$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then there exists $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

I'd like to prove the Mean Value Theorem, assuming Rolle's Theorem has already been proved.

**Proof**

Let $f$ be the function whose graph is the chord between the endpoints $(a,f(a))$, and $(b,f(b))$.

Then let $g(x)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a)$, and let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, so $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Note that $h(a)=h(b)=0$, and so the hypotheses of Rolle's Theorem are met, and thus there exists a $c\in(a,b)\ni h'(c)=0$.

$$0=h'(c)=f'(c)-g'(c)=f'(c)-\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ $$\implies f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is the above proof valid (and are there any suggestions for improvement?)

Comment: This is correct, and is usually the way most textbooks prove this result as well.

Comment: What do you mean by " $f$ be the function whose graph is the chord between the endpoints $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Comment: @Iota:  I mean that the function $f$ has a graph such that it is the chord/ curve between the two endpoints on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: I believe that the first sentence of the proof should read 

"Let $g$ be the function whose graph is ....".

Then the following sentence should be 

"Then the equation for $g$ is $g(x) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}(x-a) + f(a)$."

Then the next sentence should be "Now let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ ...", because it's not logically connected to the previous clause. With these edits, you get something that (a) makes sense, (b) is a correct proof, and (c) has decent prose structure. :)

Comment: Instead of writing the chord line, you could just write that $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ as, being a chord/curve is sort of unclear language and it is actually the property of continuity that allows you to treat it as a curve. However, since this is already given in the hypothesis, you can do without writing anything like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way to prove the MVT:

Let us define a function $\phi$:[a,b]$\rightarrow IR$ by
$$\begin{matrix}
f(x)&g(x)&h(x) \\
f(a)&g(a)&h(a)\\
f(b)&g(b)&h(b)
\end{matrix}$$
Observe that $\phi (a)$=$\phi (b)$=0. Hence by Rolle's theorem $\exists$ c $\in$ (a,b) such that $\phi^{'} (c)$=0.
$$\begin{matrix}
f^{'}(x)&g^{'}(x)&h^{'}(x) \\
f(a)&g(a)&h(a)\\
f(b)&g(b)&h(b)
\end{matrix}$$
is equal to 0.Take h(x) to be a constant function,g(x)=x and expand the determinant to get the desired result.