# Why does $f(a) = 0$ when proving the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When searching for a proof of the Mean Value Theorem, I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580790/proving-the-mean-value-theorem). It defined a function $g(x)$ where $g(x)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a)$. Later on, the answer used the derivative of $g(x)$, where $g'(x)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Why didn't $g'(x)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} +f'(a)$?

Comment: $f(a)$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable in the function $g(x)$ is $x$ and the function defined by $h(x)=f(a)$ is a constant thus $h'(x)=0$.

Comment: Could you help me with this please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292324/show-the-quotient-space-of-a-finite-collection-of-disjoint-2-simplices-obtained? Thank you!